# Reading XML in C# multiple levels

Tags: c#, xml

Hey guys i need some help getting all elements of an XML file into a variable.

this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<labels>
    <label>
        <product>Prod. 1</product>
        <colour>947 - Gold</colour>
        <size>15</size>
        <barcode>INT0919890</barcode>
        <amount>15</amount>
    </label>
    <label>
        <product>Prod. 4</product>
        <colour>942 - Silver</colour>
        <size>66</size>
        <barcode>INT0912390</barcode>
        <amount>16</amount>
    </label>
    <label>
        <product>Prod. 8</product>
        <colour>947 - Gold</colour>
        <size>19</size>
        <barcode>INT0932490</barcode>
        <amount>11</amount>
    </label>
</labels>
```

how can i make it so my program gets the first label, puts it into variables so i can use my other functions. and then continues to the next??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing with LINQ to XML (return strongly typed anonymous objects):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml_file);
var labels = from l in xdoc.Root.Elements()
             select new {
                 Product = (string)l.Element("product"),
                 Colour = (string)l.Element("colour"),
                 Size = (int)l.Element("size"),
                 Barcode = (string)l.Element("barcode"),
                 Amount = (int)l.Element("amount")
             };
```

Usage:

```
foreach(var label in labels)
{
    // use label.Product etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks and now the Product, Colour, etc are just normal variables and i can call in the function in the Foreach loop right??

Comment: @djkevino give it a try ;)